# JSON to JSON Transform of input sample using any existing java library/tools

Tags: java, json, jackson, jolt, json-patch

Input:

```
 {
   "Student": {
      "name" :"abc",
      "id"   : 588, 
      "class : "12"
   }
 }
```

Reqired Output:

```
 {
   "Student": {

      "key" :"name",
      "value":"abc",

      "key" :"id",
      "value":"588",

      "key" :"class",
      "value":"12"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your output json invalid. Json object can not duplicate key .

You can use the library `org.json` and do something like this:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(inputJson);
    JSONObject outputJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    for (Object key : jsonObject.keySet()) {
       JSONObject item = new JSONObject();

       String keyStr = (String)key;
       Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);
       item.put(keyStr, keyvalue);
       array.put(item);

    }
    outputJson.put("Student", array);
    System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Output :

```
 {
    "Student": [

        {
            "key": "name",
            "value": "abc"
        },

        {
            "key": "id",
            "value": "588"
        },
        {
            "key": "class",
            "value": "12"
        }
    ]

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, the desired output JSON format is not valid.

The closest valid output would be

```
{
  "Student" : [ {
    "key" : "name",
    "value" : "abc"
  }, {
    "key" : "id",
    "value" : 588
  }, {
    "key" : "class",
    "value" : "12"
  } ]
}
```

This can be generated via Jolt with the following spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Student": {
        "name": {
          "$": "Student[0].key",
          "@": "Student[0].value"
        },
        "id": {
          "$": "Student[1].key",
          "@": "Student[1].value"
        },
        "class": {
          "$": "Student[2].key",
          "@": "Student[2].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to solve with [JSLT](https://github.com/schibsted/jslt) if we assume the output is made valid JSON by making an array of key/value objects like the other respondents do.

The `array` function converts an object into an array of key/value objects exactly like you ask for, so the transform becomes:

```
{"Student" : array(.Student)}
```